# snmpgetnext OID on incomplete table index

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have an SNMP table which has 3 indexes:

> TABLEOID.FIELD.X.Y.Z,
>   where X, Y and Z are the indexes.

Using the following command line:

```
snmpbulkget -v2c -p public 192.168.0.1 TABLEOID.FIELD.1.1 -Cr10 -Cn0
```

Is the above request valid according to the SNMP V2 Specification?

And for this request:

```
snmpbulkget -v2c -p public 192.168.0.1 TABLEOID.FIELD.1.1.1 -Cr10 -Cn0
```

the response must be:

- TABLEOID.**FIELD**.1.1.1 (and following OIDs)

or

- TABLEOID.**FIELD+1**.1.1.1 (and following OIDs)

Answer (score 0):

> snmpbulkget -v2c -p public 192.168.0.1 TABLEOID.FIELD.1.1 -Cr10 -Cn0
>
> Is the above request valid according to the SNMP V2 Specification?

Yes. And it will return (assuming it exists):

TABLEOID.**FIELD**.1.1.1 (and/or following OIDs)

> snmpbulkget -v2c -p public 192.168.0.1 TABLEOID.FIELD.1.1.1 -Cr10 -Cn0
>
> the response must be:
>
> TABLEOID.FIELD.1.1.1 (and following OIDs)
>
> or
>
> TABLEOID.FIELD+1.1.1.1 (and following OIDs)

Neither of those. The response will be (assuming it exists):

TABLEOID.**FIELD**.1.1.2 (and/or following OIDs)

The get-bulk request returns values that are *lexicographically greater* than the OID of the request. "Lexicographically greater" essentially means dictionary order (if each subidentifier were a letter), following the OID of the request. What you are saying here is "give me up to 10 of the next OIDs following TABLEOID.FIELD.1.1.1". That does not include TABLEOID.FIELD.1.1.1 itself.